# Is DNS query a UDP or TCP?

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, tcp

I know that when we  first type an address on the URL and enter. The DNS query starts. I don't who initiates, but my guess is application will only initiate the DNS query. The DNS query already knows which IP to contact to get the information ( DNS server is preset). SO, the application will put the Domain name in the payload, the Transport layer will put as UDP or TCP ( I don't know , i.e.also the question), the src and destination IP will be put by Network layer. In DNS we already know the DNS server IP ( this is destination IP), a response will come back. This will be the destination IP. Now, the rest of the communication can happen. As we know that http is TCP. But, I don't know is DNS query a tcp or udp? Please correct my understanding also if you find something wrong here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Protocol_details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many things, *it depends*.

DNS queries are generally handled over UDP. If you do an A record lookup for "www.google.com" (which is what happens when you go to www.google.com in your browser) the answer that comes back will be in a UDP packet.

If the query is for a large record (>512 bytes), like a big DKIM key, then the DNS request will use TCP.

Comment: I have updated my question, please do respond.

Comment: If you like my reworded question, then please remove my ban.

Comment: Most DNS servers support EDNS0 these days so can negotiate a UDP max packet size, usually 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The PPPoE protocol has a way for the two ends of the protocol to negotiate with each other. The ISP offers you an IP address and your router accepts it. Then your ISP sends you a bunch of other parameters such as the name servers to use.

Comment: How ISP can offer me an IP address, when I got connected for the first time? In my opinion, I would have done DHCPDISCOVER, and then things would have fallen at place. But, the question is at what address will I broadcast? This is also not known. Please throw some light on it. I am new to networking, please bear with me.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI I think you need to do WAY more reading and narrow your problem scopes before asking questions, as your questions are border-line nonsensical.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI Why would you do a DHCPDISCOVER? Your link to your ISP doesn't use DHCP, it uses PPPoE. DHCP is, as you noted, a broadcast protocol. Your link to your ISP is point to point -- that's the "PPP" in PPoE.